# How to show $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$?

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid where $X_i \sim \text{exponential}(\theta)$

I am trying to show that $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$.

As I understand it, it is sufficient to show that  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \text{Bias}_\theta(\hat{\theta},\theta) = 0$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \text{Var}_\theta(\hat{\theta}) = 0$$

I already showed that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \text{Bias}_\theta(\hat{\theta},\theta) = 0$

I calculated the variance to be $$\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}-\left(\frac{n\theta}{(n-1)}\right)^2$$

But the limit of this is $-\theta^2$ which isn't zero.

Did I make a mistake? If not, what is the intuition behind why the MLE isn't consistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variance isn't correct.  You are missing a factor of $n^2$ in the numerator of the first term.

If $\bar X^{-1}$ is your estimator for $\theta$ for the sample $$X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\theta)$$ with common PDF $$f_X(x) = \theta e^{-\theta x}, \quad x > 0, \quad \theta > 0,$$ then the PDF of the sum $$Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = n\bar X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n, \theta)$$ with PDF $$f_Y(y) = \frac{\theta^n y^{n-1} e^{-\theta y}}{\Gamma(n)}, \quad n > 0, \theta > 0, y > 0,$$ hence the distribution of $\bar X$ is $\bar X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n, n\theta)$ with PDF $$f_{\bar X}(x) = \frac{(n\theta)^n x^{n-1} e^{-n\theta x}}{\Gamma(n)}, \quad n > 0, \theta > 0, x > 0.$$  The distribution of $W = \bar X^{-1}$ is therefore **inverse gamma**:  $$f_W(w) = \frac{1}{w^2} \cdot \frac{(n\theta)^n w^{-(n-1)} e^{-n\theta / w}}{\Gamma(n)} = \frac{(n\theta)^n e^{-n\theta /w}}{w^{n+1} \Gamma(n)}.$$  If we accept that the integral of $f_W(w)$ for $w > 0$ is $1$ for any legitimate choice of $n, \theta$, then we can compute the $k^{\rm th}$ raw moments as follows:  $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}[W^k] &= \int_{w=0}^\infty w^k f_W(w) \, dw \\ &= \frac{(n\theta)^n}{\Gamma(n)} \int_{w=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-n\theta/w}}{w^{n-k+1}} \, dw \\ &= \frac{(n\theta)^k \Gamma(n-k)}{\Gamma(n)} \int_{w=0}^\infty \frac{(n\theta)^{n-k} e^{-n\theta/w}}{w^{n-k+1} \Gamma(n-k)} \, dw \\ &=  \frac{(n\theta)^k \Gamma(n-k)}{\Gamma(n)}, \end{align*} $$ since the last integral is for an inverse gamma PDF with parameters $n-k$ and $n\theta$, which equals $1$.  Therefore, for $k = 1$ we recover the expectation $$\operatorname{E}[\bar X^{-1}] = \frac{n\theta}{n-1}, \quad n > 1,$$ and for $k = 2$ we get $$\operatorname{E}[(\bar X^{-1})^2] = \frac{n^2 \theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}, \quad n > 2.$$  Therefore the variance is $$\operatorname{Var}[\bar X^{-1}] = \frac{n^2 \theta^2}{(n-1)^2 (n-2)},$$ and the asymptotic variance as $n \to \infty$ is simply $0$, as desired.

Comment: Why is there a factor of $\frac{1}{w^2}$ in the definition of $f_W(w)$? The Wikipedia page for the inverse gamma function doesn't include this factor.

Comment: if $X$ has PDF $f_X(x)$, then for a monotone transformation $Y = g(X)$, the PDF of $Y$ is $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy}\right|,$$ so in our case $g(x) = 1/x$, and $|dg^{-1}/dw| = 1/w^2$.  This is where the factor comes from.  Then when you simplify, you get the inverse gamma density that is written at the end of the above equation you are referring to, after combining like powers of $w$.

Comment: Amazingly helpful! Thanks! I had never heard nor had any idea how to use the inverse gamma until this post. Fantastic!